# How do you programmatically check if a spreadsheet has headers in C#

Tags: c#, excel, filepath

I am creating a winform application where every day, a user will select a xlsx file with the day's shipping information to be merged with our invoicing data.

The challenge I am having is when the user does not download the xlsx file with the specification that the winform data requires. (I wish I  could eliminate this step with an API connection but sadly I cannot)

My first step is checking to see if the xlsx file has headers to that my file path is valid

Example

```
string connString = "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + *path* + "';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;';";
```

Where *path* is returned from an OpenFileDialog box

If the file was chosen wasn't downloaded with headers the statement above throws an exception.

If change HDR=YES; to HDR=NO; then I have trouble identifying the columns I need and if the User bothered to include the correct ones.

My code then tries to load the data into a DataTable

```
    private void loadRows() 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < deliveryTable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = deliveryTable.Rows[i];
            int deliveryId = 0;
            bool result = int.TryParse(dr[0].ToString(), out deliveryId);
            if (deliveryId > 1 && !Deliveries.ContainsKey(deliveryId))
            {
                var delivery = new Delivery(deliveryId)
                {
                    SalesOrg = Convert.ToInt32(dr[8]),
                    SoldTo = Convert.ToInt32(dr[9]),
                    SoldName = dr[10].ToString(),
                    ShipTo = Convert.ToInt32(dr[11]),
                    ShipName = dr[12].ToString(),
                };
```

Which all works only if the columns are in the right place.
If they are not in the right place my thought is to display a message to the user to get the right information

Does anyone have any suggestions?
(Sorry, first time posting a question and still learning to think through it)

Comment: What exception are you getting?  What is the line of code the produces the exception?  What you have posted is just a string concatenation so I doubt the exception you are getting is there.

Comment: The exception thrown was "Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format." When I change HDR=NO; I don't get this exception so I assumed a header could not be found (and indeed one isn't present in the spreadsheet)

Comment: You get an exception.  That's how you know.  If you want to limp along anyway then you'll have to consider reading the spreadsheet another way.  Lots of OpenXml wrappers around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're loading the spreadsheet into a Datatable? Hard to tell with one line of code.  I would use the columns collection in the datatable and check to see if all the columns you want are there.  Sample code to enumerate the columns below.

```
private void PrintValues(DataTable table)
{
    foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        foreach(DataColumn column in table.Columns)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(row[column]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, I updated the question with more code and you are correct about my next step. I suppose I could wrap in a try catch block and report back to the user an error message on fail??

Comment: Yep - i would hold a list of expected columns and de-queue them as and when you find them, if the list isn't empty at the end of the loop, throw an exception with the list of columns not found in the error message to the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
     private void GetExcelSheetForUpload(string PathName, string UploadExcelName)
        {
            string excelFile = "DateExcel/" + PathName;
            OleDbConnection objConn = null;
            System.Data.DataTable dt = null;
            try
            {
    
                DataSet dss = new DataSet();
                String connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Persist Security Info=True;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml;Data Source=" + PathName;
                objConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
                objConn.Open();
                dt = objConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                if (dt == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                String[] excelSheets = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
                int i = 0;
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        excelSheets[i] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + excelSheets[i] + "]", objConn);
                        OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                        oleda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        oleda.Fill(dss, "TABLE");
    
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                grdExcel.DataSource = dss.Tables[0].DefaultView;
                grdExcel.DataBind();
                lblTotalRec.InnerText = Convert.ToString(grdExcel.Rows.Count);
    
            }
    
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewState["Fuletypeidlist"] = "0";
                grdExcel.DataSource = null;
                grdExcel.DataBind();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (objConn != null)
                {
                    objConn.Close();
                    objConn.Dispose();
                }
                if (dt != null)
                {
                    dt.Dispose();
                }
            }
    
        }


 if (grdExcel.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text.ToString() == "CODE")
                {
                    GetExcelSheetForEmpl(PathName);
                }
                else
                {
                    divStatusMsg.Style.Add("display", "");
                    divStatusMsg.Attributes.Add("class", "alert alert-danger alert-dismissable");
                    divStatusMsg.InnerText = "ERROR !!... Upload Excel Sheet in header Defined Format ";
                }
```